# Should I use Perl's LWP or lib curl?

Tags: perl

As I understand that (from HTTP client perspective) we have LWP and libcurl (WWW::Curl) available in Perl. Do we have any criteria which one to choose?

Comment: Yes. libcurl is the way to go. Great software by a guy who cares about software quality; and great support from an active user/developer mailing list.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just talking from an API perspective, I prefer LWP.  The problem with Curl is that it's very obviously made off of a C library.  For instance:

```
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$response_body);

my $retcode = $curl->perform;
if ($retcode == 0) {
    # Response is now in $response_body
}
else {
    die "Error\n";
}
```

Setting parameters with `setopt()`? Returning the response using a reference to one of those parameters?  Having a method return 0 on success? These things are idiomatic in C code, but not in modern OO Perl.

Here's roughly the same code in LWP:

```
my $response = $lwp->get('http://example.com');
if( $response->is_success ) {
    $response_body = $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die "Error\n";
}
```

The call to `is_success()` is more self-documenting and blends better inside an OO language. C coders got used to seeing code like `if($retcode == 0)` on success for historical reasons, but there's no reason Perl coders should pick up this habit.  The above also shows how LWP easily takes care of content decoding for us, which Curl leaves for you to do.

It's not shown above, but Curl also forces you to handle GET/POST parameter parsing on your own. In LWP, you pass a hash and it breaks down the `name=value` pairs for you.  Cookies, too.  Curl is very low-level that way.

Curl may well be faster, but ask yourself how much that will matter in your application. Are you really going to send 100 requests in a short period of time?  If so, then Curl may well be worth it.  If not, then go for ease of implementation, which I think LWP is going to win without much of a fight.

Answer (score 11):

LWP is the most commonly used, and works with the de-facto standard modules like HTTP::Request, HTTP::Headers, HTTP::Cookies, etc. WWW::Curl is sometimes more powerful and sometimes faster, but has the kind of weird interface that makes it blatantly obvious that it's wrapping a C library. I would use LWP unless there's some reason not to.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on your requirements and expectations. I think libcurl and LWP have slightly different feature sets and they perform slightly different.

See this [libcurl vs LWP performance tests](https://web.archive.org/web/20120630125418/http://ivan-bg.org/2008/08/lwp-vs-httplite-vs-wwwcurl.html) or [this](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-09/0167.html). I would urge you to run your own comparison for your own features and surroundings to make it really relevant.

(Disclaimer: I am the main author of libcurl)

Comment: The first link now appears to be broken.

Answer (score 6):

I like using [Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) now. I even [wrote about it for the 2011 Perl Advent Calendar](http://www.perladvent.org/2011/2011-12-11.html).

There's not really an answer to your general question though. You use the right tool for your job. Without knowing what you are trying to do, it's virtually impossible to guide you. Learn both, and then choose the one that makes your task easier. One might have better knobs and dials for what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer LWP because it is a core perl module. To interact with web services, commandline tool curl has some convenience features like the --*anyauth* option, and you can also easily issue HTTP PUT and HTTP DELETE requests. I think PUT and DELETE were [added as convenience methods to LWP just recently in 2011](https://github.com/gisle/libwww-perl/pull/10), correct me if I'm wrong.